# Is it possible to start a PIvotal GemFire Server, Locator and Client in one JVM?

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I want to start a Pivotal GemFire Server, Locator and client in a single JVM with *Spring Boot*.

The server and Locator start OK (I used "start-locator" in server `gemfire.properties`).

However, when I tried to start the client connected to the locator, I got an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A connection to a distributed system already exists in this VM. 

    at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.internal.InternalDistributedSystem.validateSameProperties(InternalDistributedSystem.java:3054)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.DistributedSystem.connect(DistributedSystem.java:1642)
```

And, in the Exception, the existing properties that server used to connect to the Locator is printed out.

Here is the code at client:

```
@Bean(name = "GemfireClientProperties")
Properties gemfireClientProperties() {
    Properties gemfireProperties = new Properties();
    gemfireProperties.setProperty("mcast-port", "0");
    gemfireProperties.setProperty("log-level", "config");
    return gemfireProperties;
}


@Bean(name = "GemfireClientPool")
PoolFactoryBean gemfireClientPool() {
    PoolFactoryBean gemfirePool = new PoolFactoryBean();
    gemfirePool.setRetryAttempts(1);
    gemfirePool.setLocators(Collections.singletonList(new ConnectionEndpoint("localhost", 17202)));
    return gemfirePool;
}


@Bean(name = "clientCache")
ClientCache clientCache(@Qualifier("GemfireClientProperties") Properties gemfireClientProperties) {
    ClientCacheFactory clientCacheFactory = new ClientCacheFactory(gemfireClientProperties);
    return clientCacheFactory.create();
}
```

Pivotal GemFire version is 8.2.5.

I traced in debug mode, the exception is thrown at the  clientCacheFactory.create() line, and in the method, the properties file passed in is correct, which has only 2 entries.

Does Pivotal GemFire have some limitation such that I cannot connect this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, NO, you cannot have a peer `Cache` instance (with embedded Locator) and a `ClientCache` instance in the same JVM (or Java application process).

In Apache Geode/Pivotal GemFire, the cache instance, whether a peer `Cache` (a peer member of the distributed system, or cluster), or a `ClientCache` instance, is a ***Singleton***.
Therefore, there can only be 1 GemFire cache instance per JVM (or more technically, `ClassLoader`, but we will not go down that ugly road).

Anyway, when a cache instance already exists, then any subsequent cache creation attempt say, a `ClientCache` instance creation using GemFire's [`o.a.g.cache.client.ClientCacheFactory`](http://gemfire-95-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/client/ClientCacheFactory.html) (when a peer `Cache` instance, created by the [`o.a.g.cache.CacheFactory`](http://gemfire-95-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/CacheFactory.html), already exists) will result in a check where GemFire pretty much expects the cache instances to be the same (i.e. a peer `Cache` exists, therefore better be attempting to create the same (by configuration, anyway) "peer" `Cache` instance).  Clearly a `ClientCache` instance will not have the same (distributed system) configuration as a peer `Cache` instance, and there for fails.

You can see the logic beginning [here](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/rel/v1.6.0/geode-core/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/cache/client/ClientCacheFactory.java#L219).  The first thing that a cache instance creation does is check and lookup an existing cache instance.  A `ClientCache` instance cannot have the `locators` and `mcast-port` properties set ([here](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/rel/v1.6.0/geode-core/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/cache/client/ClientCacheFactory.java#L222-L241)); if they are, it results in an error (usually another diff between client and peer cache instances, particular for the `locators` property).

If the existing instance is not closed or closing, then it is going to [validate the configuration](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/rel/v1.6.0/geode-core/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/cache/client/ClientCacheFactory.java#L245-L258).  Pretty much the only way to create another cache instance is when it is the same instance.  The configuration validation is quite extensive.

There have been discussion about changing the "***Singletone***" nature of the GemFire cache instances on the Apache Geode dev lists, but nothing has materialized in this regard yet as it is a major undertaking, partially because the **static** `(Client)CacheFactory.getAnyInstance()` (or worse, `GemFireCacheImpl.getInstance()`; both peer and client cache instances share the same base class... `org.apache.geode.cache.internal.GemFireCacheImpl`) was used extensively throughout the codebase rather than passing the cache instance to the dependent GemFire objects/components, e.g. like *Regions*.

Anyway, sorry this answer does not provide you with any relief.

However, I often times create 2 separate *Spring Boot* application (classes) to configure and bootstrap both a [client](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/boot-example/src/main/java/example/app/geode/cache/client/BootExampleApplication.java) and 1 or more [servers](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/boot-example/src/main/java/example/app/geode/cache/server/GeodeServerApplication.java), individually.

On the server, I even use a [Spring profile to active a Locator/Manager](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/boot-example/src/main/java/example/app/geode/cache/server/GeodeServerApplication.java#L62-L66) in a single server instance so that I can form a small cluster (with the [embedded Locator](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/boot-example/src/main/java/example/app/geode/cache/server/GeodeServerApplication.java#L64)) and [Manager](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/boot-example/src/main/java/example/app/geode/cache/server/GeodeServerApplication.java#L65) so that I can also connect up to this cluster using *Gfsh*.

So, you can use the same class to start a small cluster.  The first server would be stated with:

```
$java -cp ... -Dspring.profiles.active=locator-manager example.app.geode.cache.server. GeodeServerApplication
```

And subsequence servers, joining the first server, would be started using:

```
$java -cp ... -Dspring.data.gemfire.name=ServerTwo -Dspring.data.gemfire.cache.server.port=42424 example.app.geode.cache.server. GeodeServerApplication
```

NOTE, you must be careful to very the member name (using the `spring.data.gemfire.name` property since GemFire requires peer member names to be unique) and you must vary the `CacheServer` port (used by cache clients to connect; hence the `spring.data.gemfire.cache.server.port` property) otherwise you will hit a `java.net.BindException`, since by default the `CacheServer` listens on port `40404`.

The well-known SDG (System) properties are the easiest way to vary the configuration and get a small cluster running (without *Gfsh* even; cool!).

Comment: What if I still want to have cache and client cache on the same JVM and "go down this ugly road"? Any hints on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is known limitation, you can't have more than one cache per JVM (other than a server with an embedded locator).
Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, do you have a documentation/link for this limitation?

Comment: Nop, I couldn't find any documentation link that explicitly specifies this limitation, but I know it from experience (and also by looking at the source code).